# Unable to resolve dependencies react native google fit

Tags: react-native, google-fit

After adding the package I can't build the project. Error:

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-google-fit'.
      > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-google-fit:_debugPublishCopy'.
         > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0.
           Searched in the following locations:
               file:/Users/wojciech/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.6.0/play-services-auth-11.6.0.pom
               file:/Users/wojciech/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.6.0/play-services-auth-11.6.0.jar
               file:/Users/wojciech/Documents/dev/uni/swifty-app/Swifty/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.6.0/play-services-auth-11.6.0.jar
               file:/Users/wojciech/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.6.0/play-services-auth-11.6.0.pom
               file:/Users/wojciech/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.6.0/play-services-auth-11.6.0.jar
               file:/Users/wojciech/Documents/dev/uni/swifty-app/Swifty/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.6.0/play-services-auth-11.6.0.jar
           Required by:
               Swifty:react-native-google-fit:unspecified
         > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:11.6.0.
           Searched in the following locations:
               file:/Users/wojciech/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-fitness/11.6.0/play-services-fitness-11.6.0.pom
               file:/Users/wojciech/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-fitness/11.6.0/play-services-fitness-11.6.0.jar
               file:/Users/wojciech/Documents/dev/uni/swifty-app/Swifty/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-fitness/11.6.0/play-services-fitness-11.6.0.jar
               file:/Users/wojciech/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-fitness/11.6.0/play-services-fitness-11.6.0.pom
               file:/Users/wojciech/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-fitness/11.6.0/play-services-fitness-11.6.0.jar
               file:/Users/wojciech/Documents/dev/uni/swifty-app/Swifty/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-fitness/11.6.0/play-services-fitness-11.6.0.jar
           Required by:
               Swifty:react-native-google-fit:unspecified
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only because this is a very common error on StackOverflow React Native questions, I have to ask: did you follow the instructions to completion? This is a native module so just adding the package won't work; you need to also do the linking and for this particular package, some manual steps as well. In addition to this, if you are using `react-react-native-app` or `Expo`, this will not work without ejecting/detaching.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways to solve it. 
 1. add to your android/build.gradle file, under allprojects/repositoris sections

```
maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
}
```

so that it should looks like:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

2. Another way (works for me) - for react-native-google-fit lib, and in android/build.gradle of library change dependency to

   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth+'

   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness+'

And use your fork in your project